# Eclipse, Toolbar > Run button: in the drop-down menu, what do the numbers between parentheses following the class names mean?

Tags: java, eclipse, memory

When I click the little triangle next to the toolbar's Run button to open its drop-down menu, I see that some of my runnable classes are followed by a parenthesised number (always 1) - see attached screenshot.

Do these numbers mean that instances of the class they follow are somehow currently running (they should not be)? If so, how can I terminate them? Or do these numbers mean something else altogether?

And could it also explain that when I open my Task Manager, I see that a 'resting' Eclipse consumes ~480 MB of memory? That seems a lot - which is how I got the idea that something is running in the background.

I am on Windows 8.1, and use Eclipse version 2018-09 (4.9.0).

[image]

Comment: They mean you already had a test configuration with that name. When you create another one (often by just running a test class), Eclipse fixes the name clash by adding (1) and later (2) etc. You can always go to the Run Configurations and rename them. You can also delete any test configuration that's no longer relevant.

Comment: @RobSpoor That makes a lot of sense. Thanks!